# Appropriate Preposition

Tags: prepositions

Question: Which preposition is appropriate for the following sentence?

Given: He has no taste (in/for) music.

Comment: Either is appropriate, depending on what sense is intended.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on what you are trying to say:

> *He has **no taste for music**.*

This means that he doesn't care much for music.

> *He has **no taste in music***.

This means that he doesn't like good music, he only likes bad music (in the opinion of the speaker, at least).